# Issue with object scope

Tags: c++

I have a very strange error with C++. I am trying to implement my own hashtable as an exercise, and I wrote a test script:

```
void test_put(){
    HashMap<int, int, IntHash<int> > hmap(MEDIUM_SIZE);
    std::vector<int> nums;
    for(int i = 0; i < MEDIUM_SIZE/2; i++){
        nums.push_back(i*i);
        hmap.put(i*i, i*i);
    }
    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < MEDIUM_SIZE/2; i++){
        assert(hmap.get(i*i, value));
        assert(value == i*i);
        
        assert(!hmap.get((i*i)-2, value));
    }

    cout << "Put Test Pass!" << endl;

}

void test_reallocation(){
    HashMap<int, int, IntHash<int> > hmap(SMALL_SIZE);
    std::vector<int> nums;

    int value;
    for(int i = 0; i < MEDIUM_SIZE/2; i++){
        nums.push_back(i*i);
        hmap.put(i*i, i*i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MEDIUM_SIZE/2; i++){
        assert(hmap.get(i*i, value));
        assert(value == i*i);
        
        assert(!hmap.get((i*i)-2, value));
    }

    cout << "Reallocation Test Pass!" << endl;
}

int main () {
    test_put();
    test_reallocation();
}
```

The strange thing is, when I run test_reallocation() after test_put(), I get a segmentation fault. However, when I comment out test_put(), my test passes. I'm a little confused how running one function causes the next to segfault, when they have different function scopes. Could anybody shed light on the issue?

Comment: Q: What is MEDIUM_SIZE?  SMALL_SIZE?  Q: What is your C++ compiler/compiler version?  Q: Have you tried debugging interactively yet?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Run your program in the debugger, 2) Single step until you get the exception, 3) Update your post and show us the line it's crashing on.   ... and... Q: Please give more details about your `HashMap`!  A *COMPLETE* example would help: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @paulsm4 will do!

Comment: At a guess `hmap.put` is doing something horrible to the heap...